# How to call back the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this simple code.

```
myobj.job('first', function (one, two){

   console.log("First");

});

myobj.job('second', function (one, two){

   console.log("Second");

});
```

Now the question is:

how **myobj** could call one of these depending on the event('first' or 'second') occurred?

Thanks

Comment: Too vague. Try rephrasing it.

Comment: @Raynos I mean how can i create custom event and call them when they occurs.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Here's an example implementation -- http://jsfiddle.net/6Jv5n/1

Comment: Perfect! it's what i was looking for.... other question can i also do something like.... myobj.job('first').other() ? how to change the code to accept also this syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be looking for more functionality in the future for event emitters/listeners so you might take a look at some ready built modules:

## EventEmitter2

https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2

### Features

- Namespaced events Wildcards for
- namespaces Times To Listen (TTL),
- extends the once concept Browser
- environment compatibility As good or
- better performance for emission and
- listener registration as Node.js core
- EventEmitter Smaller.
- EventEmitter2.js (2.2K Minified) VS.
- events.js (2.7K Minified)

## Hook.io

https://github.com/Marak/hook.io

hook.io creates a distributed node.js EventEmitter that works cross-process / cross-platform / cross-browser.

You create custom i/o scenarios by picking and choosing from an extensive library of tiny, independent, autonomous "hooks" that seamlessly work together.

---

Take a look at the source code for those and it'll give you a good idea how to work well with emitting events.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs & EventEmitter answer:
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/events.html

```
function myobj()
{
   // constructor
}

util.inherits(myobj, process.EventEmitter)

myobj.prototype.hereComesEvent1 = function()
{
   // do stuff
   // ..
   // fire event
   this.emit('first', 1, 2);
}

myobj.prototype.hereComesEvent2 = function()
{
   // do stuff
   // ..
   // fire event
   this.emit('second', 'one', 'two');
}


// test myobj

var mo = new myobj();
mo.on('first', function(a, b) {
   console.log([a, b]);
});
mo.on('second', function(a, b) {
   console.log([a, b]);
});

mo.hereComesEvent1();
mo.hereComesEvent2();
```